# explode comma from an array value in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

> I want to explode coma from an array value.
>   My code is.

```
        $to_ids_string = "";            
        $to_id = $this->input->post('to');            
        for ($r = 0; $r < count($this->input->post('to')); $r++) {
            if ($to_ids_string != "") {
                $to_ids_string = $to_ids_string . "," . $to_id[$r];
            } else {
                $to_ids_string = $to_id[$r];
            }                
        }
       echo $to_ids_string;
            $a = explode(',', $to_ids_string);
            foreach ($a as $item) {
                echo("<li>$item</li>");
                exit;
            }
```

> when i echo $to_ids_string it will return 2,3 but when i loop in foreach it only return 2 not show 3.

Comment: remove exit; from foreach. add it after completion of foreach. You are breaking it after one iteration

Comment: remove exit and print the $a array to see there are one element or two element

Answer (score 2):

Because of your exit, if you use exit like that, then it is the end of your program and it doesn't echo anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to remove `exit;` from foreach loop. When you write `exit`, execution of your code stops. Hence you are not getting desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Happens due to `exit`. 
Please remove `exit` from your code.